# Google Sheets importxml for New York Times

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets

For months, I've stuck in this tough issue.

Please visit this link for details:

[Goal]

> By importxml, it is to get the data and its a href link in Google
>   Sheets, but I failed in bringing the link in. Let me know how to bring
>   the href link in B2.

[Problem]

> A href link doesn't have its class.

Please visit the link below to see the detail because I'm new to Stackoverflow and not qualified to upload an image. Sorry about it.

[The codes below should work, but it doesn't produce any result]
I think there's an xpath grammar error.

Namely,
A2: http://www.nytimes.com/pages/world/index.html
B2: =importxml(A2, ʺ//div[@class='story']|//div[@class='thumbnail']//a/@hrefʺ)

B2 doesn't show any result.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/docs/importxml$20new$20york$20times/docs/4-IJJ6_h5Pw/prNdITEsQ4AJ

Comment: Off-site explanations and videos are not helpful on Stackoverflow. We need the following, _on-site_ (edit your question): The URL of the page you are importing, what exactly you are trying to find on the page and finally: what exactly you would like to appear in a sheets cell as the result of the import. Do not explain those things, _show_ them.

Comment: Thank you! But, I'm a starter and have insufficient points to upload an image to show.

Comment: Thanks for editing, the one thing that is still missing: the content of the cell A2, the page URL I assume.

Comment: I added A2 address, and please understand I'm a new.   :)    If you go to the edited new link and ciick 'Display image', you can see the new york times source code and what I tried.

Comment: I've added an answer, perhaps it's easier for you to comment on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still not very clear what you would like to find, but sometimes it's easier to comment on an attempted solution than trying to explain.

The formula you have shown does return results. If I add the following in my own Sheets file:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.nytimes.com/pages/world/index.html", "//div[@class='story']|//div[@class='thumbnail']//a/@href")
```

the function returns several `href` attributes, and the result looks like

> [image]

Is this what you expected or would you like to change the result?

Comment: Yes! But what's the difference between yours and mine? I can't catch it. :)  Anyway thanks!

Comment: @Latestarter I don't think there is a difference in the formula, but apparently, for no reason, it does not work if you enter the formula in cell `A2`. Try entering the formula in `A1`, writing the link directly into the formula, without referencing other cells. By the way, [now you should decide whether you'd like to accept this answer or not](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks!

Comment: There's no Accept button here. Is it because I'm a new comer.-- Do you know my orginal code is now working? What the h~  Has Google programmer been giving me hard time? Oh, my god!

Comment: @Latestarter To accept an answer, mark the tick on the left so that it appears in green. Glad you finally got it to work.